# MicrosoftTeamsPowerShell module: Difference between Get-TeamUser and Get-TeamChannelUser

Tags: powershell, module, microsoft-teams

I don't understand the difference between the two cmdlets

`Get-TeamUser`

and

`Get-TeamChannelUser`

(and respectively also the add-... version).

I am currently trying to manage a Team with 1500+ participients (mostly added from a flow w/o scripting) and have ended up with...

`(Get-TeamUser -GroupId deadbeef-dead-beaf-1234-1234567890ab).count 1570`

`(Get-TeamChannelUser -GroupId deadbeef-dead-beaf-1234-1234567890ab -DisplayName General).count 1498`

So, just to enlighten me: Add-TeamUser will have to be followed by Add-TeamChanneluser for each channel in the team?

Answer (score 3):

**Get-TeamUser** is used to retrieve the users who are members of a specific Microsoft Teams team. It gives you a list of all users who are directly added as members to the team.

**Get-TeamChannelUser** is used to retrieve the users who have been specifically added as members to a particular channel within a Microsoft Teams team. It allows you to view the users who have been added to a specific channel within the team.

If you want to add a user to the team, you can use the Add-TeamUser cmdlet. This will add the user as a member of the team. If you want to add the user specifically to a channel within the team, you would need to use the Add-TeamChannelUser cmdlet after adding them as a member of the team. This allows you to grant them access to the specific channel.

Ref Doc:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/get-teamuser?view=teams-ps
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/get-teamchanneluser?view=teams-ps